# Fyusenet works in OpenGL but not in GLES2 and EGL

Tags: opengl-es

Good Afternoon,

I’ve been working with a open source library called [fyusenet](https://github.com/Fyusion-Open-Source/fyusenet) that runs neural network using OpenGL on a target board with PowerVR GPU.

The target board just has OpenGLES and EGL and doesn’t have OpenGL / glx / glfw / GLUT / GLU / GLVND etc. The library has a sample resnet written.

I’ve been able to run the sample resnet successfully on a host Ubuntu system with OpenGL, glx and GLVND, but in the target board the second last layer, which is defined in a file called `deepgemmlayer.cpp`, is causing all the outputs to go 0. I got to know this by using a enableIntermediateOutput() API in the fyusenet library and converting the binary raw intermediate feature maps to decimals. I think it has something to do with how the shader is getting executed by GLES-EGL combination. I've tried changing the precision values, but it also ends up giving the same all zero output.

This is the deepgemmlayer’s forward [function](https://github.com/Fyusion-Open-Source/fyusenet/blob/main/fyusenet/gpu/deep/deepgemmlayer.cpp):

```
void DeepGEMMLayer::forward(uint64_t sequence) {
    if (!valid_) THROW_EXCEPTION_ARGS(FynException,"Trying to invoke forward() on invalid layer");
#ifdef DEBUG
    int err = glGetError();
    if (err != GL_NO_ERROR) FNLOGD("HINT: glerror on render entry: 0x%x (%s:%d)[%s]",err,__FILE__,__LINE__,getName().c_str());
#endif
    std::lock_guard<std::recursive_mutex> lck(processingLock_);
    if (outputChanged_) updateFBOs();
    glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glDisable(GL_STENCIL_TEST);
    glDisable(GL_CULL_FACE);
    if (tiler_->numInputTiles() <= 1) glDisable(GL_BLEND);
    else {
        glEnable(GL_BLEND);
        glBlendEquationSeparate(GL_FUNC_ADD,GL_FUNC_ADD);
        glBlendFuncSeparate(GL_ONE,GL_ONE,GL_ONE,GL_ONE);
    }
    glViewport(0, 0, viewport_[0], viewport_[1]);
    vertexArray_->bind();
    framebuffers_.at(0)->bind();
    framebuffers_.at(0)->setWriteMask();
    glClearColor(0.0f,0.0f,0.0f,0.0f);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,inputTextures_.at(0));
    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0+DISP_TEXTURE);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,inputCoordTexture_);
    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0+WEIGHT_TEXTURE);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,weightTexture_);
    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0+BIAS_TEXTURE);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,biasTexture_);
    if (flags_ & LayerFlags::RESIDUAL_INPUT) {
        if (residualTextures_.empty()) THROW_EXCEPTION_ARGS(FynException,"Residual flag configured, but no such texture found.");
        glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,residualTextures_.at(0));
    }
    if (usePoints_) {
        int instances = tiler_->numInputTiles();
        int points = tiler_->numOutputTiles();
        shader_->bind(shaderState_.get());
        shader_->setUniformValue("numInputTiles",tiler_->numInputTiles());
        glDrawArrays(GL_POINTS, 0, points);
        shader_->unbind((instances > 1) ? true : false);
        if (instances > 1) {
            noBiasShader_->bind(noBiasShaderState_.get());
            noBiasShader_->setUniformValue("numInputTiles",tiler_->numInputTiles());
            glDrawArraysInstanced(GL_POINTS, 0, points, instances-1);
            noBiasShader_->unbind();
        }
    } else {
        int instances = tiler_->numInputTiles()*kernel_;
        int tris = tiler_->numOutputTiles();
        shader_->bind(shaderState_.get());
        shader_->setUniformValue("numInputTiles",tiler_->numInputTiles());
        glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES,tris*6,GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT,(const GLvoid *)0);
        shader_->unbind((instances > 1) ? true : false);
        if (instances > 1) {
            noBiasShader_->bind(noBiasShaderState_.get());
            noBiasShader_->setUniformValue("numInputTiles",tiler_->numInputTiles());
            glDrawElementsInstanced(GL_TRIANGLES,tris*6,GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT,(const GLvoid *)0,instances-1);
            noBiasShader_->unbind();
        }
    }
    framebuffers_.at(0)->unbind();
    vertexArray_->unbind();
}
```

The vertex shader [code]https://github.com/Fyusion-Open-Source/fyusenet/blob/main/fyusenet/gpu/shaders/deep/deepconv1x1_tiled.vert) is as follows:

```
precision highp float;
precision highp int;
precision highp sampler2D;

#ifdef BINDING_SUPPORT
layout(binding=4) uniform highp sampler2D inputDisplacements;
#ifdef NO_HALF
layout(binding=5) uniform sampler2D inputCoeffs;
#else
layout(binding=5) uniform highp usampler2D inputCoeffs;
#endif
#else
uniform highp sampler2D inputDisplacements;
#ifdef NO_HALF
uniform sampler2D inputCoeffs;
#else
uniform highp usampler2D inputCoeffs;
#endif
#endif

in highp vec4 attributes0;
in highp ivec2 attributes1;
in highp vec2 attributes2;

out highp vec4 texCoord;
#ifdef NO_HALF
// requires 6 varyings in total (w/ residual)
flat out vec4 layer0coeffs[4];
#else
// requires 4 varyings in total (w/ residual)
flat out highp uvec4 layer0coeffs[2];
#endif

#ifdef USE_RESIDUAL
out highp vec2 resCoord;
#endif

uniform int numInputTiles;

void main(void) {
  gl_Position = vec4(attributes0.x,attributes0.y,0.0,1.0);
  texCoord = vec4(attributes0.z,attributes0.w,0.0,0.0);
#ifdef INSTANCE_OFFSET
  int instance = gl_InstanceID + INSTANCE_OFFSET;
#else
  int instance = gl_InstanceID;
#endif
  int intile = instance % numInputTiles;
  texCoord.xy += texelFetch(inputDisplacements,ivec2(intile,0),0).rg;
#ifdef NO_HALF
  intile *= 4;
#else
  intile *= 2;
#endif
  int ybase = attributes1.x;
  // fetch weights
  layer0coeffs[0] = texelFetch(inputCoeffs,ivec2(intile,ybase),0);
  layer0coeffs[1] = texelFetch(inputCoeffs,ivec2(intile+1,ybase),0);
#ifdef NO_HALF
  layer0coeffs[2] = texelFetch(inputCoeffs,ivec2(intile+2,ybase),0);
  layer0coeffs[3] = texelFetch(inputCoeffs,ivec2(intile+3,ybase),0);
#endif
#if !defined(NO_BIAS) || defined(POST_BATCHNORM)
  if (instance == 0) {
    texCoord.z = float(attributes1.y+1);
  } else {
    texCoord.z = 0.0;
  }
#else
  texCoord.z = 0.0;
#endif
  texCoord.w = float(attributes1.y+1);
#ifdef USE_RESIDUAL
  resCoord.xy = attributes2.xy;
#endif
}
```

The frag shader [code]https://github.com/Fyusion-Open-Source/fyusenet/blob/main/fyusenet/gpu/shaders/deep/deepconv1x1_tiled.vert) is:

```
#include "shaders/deep/convheader.inc"

#ifdef NO_HALF
// requires 6 varyings in total (w/ residual)
flat in vec4 layer0coeffs[4];
#else
// requires 4 varyings in total (w/ residual)
flat in highp uvec4 layer0coeffs[2];
#endif

#include "shaders/activation.inc"
#include "shaders/deep/batchnorm.inc"
#include "shaders/deep/computeconv.inc"
#include "shaders/deep/residual.inc"

void main(void) {
  vec2 tc = texCoord.xy;
  fragmentColor0 =  compute(texture(inputLayer0,tc),0);  
#if !defined(NO_BIAS) || defined(POST_BATCHNORM)
#ifdef POST_BATCHNORM
  fragmentColor0 = applyBN(fragmentColor0, biasTexture, ivec4(texCoord.zw,0,1));
#else
  fragmentColor0 += texelFetch(biasTexture,ivec2(int(texCoord.z),0),0);
#endif
#endif
#ifdef USE_RESIDUAL
  fragmentColor0 += residual(residualLayer0, resCoord.xy,  biasTexture, texCoord.zw);
#endif
}
```

The preprocessor directives and version information is added to the code later:

```
#version 320 es
 #define BINDING_SUPPORT
 #define GLES
 #define DISP_UNIT 4
 #define WEIGHT_UNIT 5
 #define BIAS_UNIT 6
 #define ACT_RELU
 #define POST_BATCHNORM
 #define PIXEL_PACKING 4
 #define PADDING 0
 #define KERNEL 1
 #define DILATION 1
```

Can any help me find out the issue why the shaders might be behaving in such a way that the layer’s output becomes all 0?

I’ve tried to attach the critical sections that might be causing the `deepgemmlayer` to go bad. Apologies for the long message.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Left you a comment on GH. Let's work that out there.